# Crashlytics, Firebase screen analytics and Apple's privacy concerns

Tags: ios, app-store, crashlytics

I've just integrated Crashlytics into my code, app is still waiting for review.

Just now this news broke out
https://techcrunch.com/2019/02/07/apple-glassbox-apps/

As I understand the companies mentioned in the news were using Glassbox's session replay and not just Analytics?

My question is should we be worried by using Crashlytics & Firebase's screen tracking (analytics). Will Apple object it?

Comment: They shouldn't care for those libraries as long as you're not transmitting sensitive data through analytics (e.g. user SSN's, email, DOB's, etc.).  My impression is that this is closing some of the privacy loopholes that exist when the UI is recorded (because it's not obvious or easy to detect if sensitive info is transmitted in a video feed).

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701) and [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I also assumed so.